# Exclude documentation when deploying to production

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API project in ASP .NET where I have some web services.

I use the comments of the methods to generate the help pages created by default in Visual Studio.

```
    // GET api/version
    /// <summary>
    /// Test
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string Get()
    {
        return "Last version : 74";
    }
```

It is usefull for a development environment but we don't want these pages to appear on the production environment.

Is there any way to exclude them from deployment on production?

I tried to delete the files and make sure the web services calls still works, they do, but I am not sure of which files I can delete and I am wondering if there is any safer/automatic way to do it?

Here is the list of files I have at the moment :

- ApplicationInsights.config
- App_Data
- Areas
- bin
- Content
- favicon.ico
- fonts
- Global.asax
- Scripts
- Views
- Web.config
- WsCommon.wpp.targets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing the following :

**File App_Start/RouteConfig.cs**

Ignore the route to the HelpPages in DEBUG Configuration

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
     [...]
#if DEBUG
     routes.IgnoreRoute("Help");
#endif
     [...]
}
```

**File Global.asax.cs**

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
      [...]
#if DEBUG
      AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
#endif
      [...]
}
```

**File Controllers/HomeController.cs**

Should return a 404 error instead of an index in production :

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
#if DEBUG
     return View();
#else
     return HttpNotFound();
#endif
}
```

This way, the help pages url return the help pages in Debug and 404 errors in Release. No need to do any further manipulation with the files from

Answer (score 0):

1. Publish the web site to a local folder and deploy those contents, they will only contain the essential files.
2. Deploy that folder, or if possible, just publish to your target site.

Comment: The "essential files" contain the help pages as well, I want to exclude them.

Comment: Try setting "Copy to Output Directory" property of the file to Do not copy, and make sure that in the Project Properties, Output/XML Documentation file field is not set.